# Catch application error on restart or shutdown?

Tags: debugging, winapi, mfc

Occasionally when I restart Win10 x64 I get an application error from my system tray utility in the from of:

> AppName in Title bar
> The instruction at 0xXXXXXXXXXXXXXX referenced memory at 0xXXXXXXXXXX. 
> The memory could not be read.

over the top of the `This app is preventing you from restarting`.
But there are no .dmp files created.  I have Windows set to create the dump files and in the normal course of things it does, just not this particular one on a restart/shutdown.

I also can't find anything in the Event Viewer to at least get the base address so I can do some basic math to find the offset to the instruction.

Any tips on how I can get a .dmp created for when this happens or some type of information to help diagnose the issue on reboots?

There are occasions other apps (not mine) do the same thing on a restart so not sure if this is normal?  Doesn't see like it should be.

Comment: This would help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020353/create-a-dump-file-for-an-application-whenever-it-crashes

Comment: WER is already enabled.  So are you saying if you put it in the program instead it will catch things WER doesn't?

Comment: I still have the question if this can catch things that WER doesn't?

Comment: "So are you saying if you put it in the program instead it will catch things WER doesn't?"

Yes, I guess so, you can also add valuable information to find the source of the crash